# RSpec: automatically set js: true when driver is :chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, rspec, capybara

We are using headless webkit driver for our integration tests, so we never have to open a browser window again using Selenium.

Sometimes, though, it's convenient to really see what's going on in a browser, so we have the option `driver: :chrome` when running tests, and in addition with `js: true`, this opens Chrome.

For convenience, it would be nice to automatically set `js: true` whenever the driver is set to `:chrome`, is this possible somehow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a glance at the source code it looks like by defining the `driver` in your feature should kick up Capybara anyway.

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec.rb#L21

Comment: You're absolutely correct, why didn't I see this myself? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It's a pleasure! Thanks for giving me a reason to go have a look through the code!